# Need to overlapped a CSS command I need to removed an image background.?

Tags: html, css

I have a main css file.. It is common to all my jsp. On my other jsp, I need to remove a background picture.. How can i overlapped it?

Part of the css that should be overlapped.

```
#body .header div {
    background: url(images/smiling-man.jpg) no-repeat bottom right; --> i want this   
    removed. by overlapping it with another css.

    height: 472px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 960px;   
}
```

This is what i have done.. just removing the the background does not worked and added a class overlap on the div.

```
.overlap{
    background:none;
    height: 472px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 960px;   
}
```

My HTML

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>


<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="product.css">
        <title>Lot Movement Main Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="" /></a>       
            </div>  
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="selected"><a href="index.html"><span>home</span></a></li>
                    <li>  <a href="#"><span>Product </span></a>

                        <ul>
                             <li>
                                <a href="#"><span>Input</span></a> 
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><span>Enquiry</span></a> 
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="services.html"><span>Movement</span></a></li>

                    <li><a href="contact.html"><span>contact us</span></a></li>         
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="body">
            <div class="header">
                <div id ="prodoverlap">

                        <h3>Lot Movement Tracking System</h3>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h3>AusTralAsia</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li>+630212013129 -Main</li>
                        </ul>
                    </ul>           
                </div>      
                <div>
                    <h3>europe</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>To Be Announced</li>
                    </ul>           
                </div>  
                <div>
                    <h3>canada</h3>
                    <ul>

                        <li>To Be Announced</li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>           
                </div>  
                <div>
                    <h3>middle east</h3>
                    <ul>

                        <li>To Be Announced</li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>           
                </div>  
                <div>
                    <h3>follow us:</h3>
                    <a class="facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">facebook</a>        
                    <a class="twitter" href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank">twitter</a>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>&copy Copyright 2012. All rights reserved</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</body>
</html>
```

My Main CSS

```
/* Template by freewebsitetemplates.com */
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0; 
}
#header {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0; 
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 960px;
}


#header #logo {
    float: left;
    height: 144px;
    width: 355px;
}


#header #logo img {
    border: 0;
}


#header ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 121px;
}


#header ul li a,
#header ul li a span,
#header ul li a:hover,
#header ul li a:hover span,
#header ul li.selected a,
#header ul li.selected a span
  {
    background: url(images/menu.gif);   
  }

#header ul li a
 {
    background-position: 10px 0;
    color: #2a4f5e;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
} 




#header ul li a span
{ 
    background-position: -70px 0; 
    display: block; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
} 


#header ul li a:hover { 
    background-position: -186px -37px; 
    color: #346b84;
    text-shadow: none;
} 


#header ul li a:hover span { 
    background-position: -70px -37px; 
} 
#header ul li.selected a{ 
    background-position: 10px 36px; 
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: none;
} 
#header ul li.selected a span{ 
    background-position: -70px -74px; 
} 





/*dropdown*/

#header ul ul {
    display: none;
}

    #header ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }


#header ul ul li a span
{ 
    background-position: -70px 0; 
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: none;
    display: block; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
} 


#header ul ul li a:hover { 
    background-position: -186px -37px; 
    color: #346b84;
    text-shadow: none;
} 



#body {
    background: url(images/bg-content.gif) repeat-x top left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    min-width: 960px;
}
#body .header {
    background: url(images/bg-body.gif) repeat-x bottom center; 
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}
#body .header div {
    background: url(images/smiling-man.jpg) no-repeat bottom right;
    height: 472px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 960px;   
}
#body .header div div {
    background: none;   
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 13px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 490px;
}
#body .header div h3 {
    color: #2a4f5e; 
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 18px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
#body .header div h3 span {
    display: block; 
    font-size: 25px;
}
#body .header div h3 a {
    color: #2a4f5e;
    text-decoration: none;  
}
#body .header div h3 a:hover {
    color: #507685; 
}
#body .header div p {
    color: #507685;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 12px 0 6px 0;
    padding: 0; 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
#body .header div p a {
    color: #507685; 
}
#body .header div p a:hover {
    color: #2a4f5e; 
}
#body .header ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 49px 0 0;
}
#body .header ul li {
    float: left;    
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
#body .body {
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    margin: 0 auto 34px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 2px;
    width: 954px;
}   
#body .body div {
    float: left;    
}
#body .body .section {
    background: url(images/bg-section.gif) repeat-x top left;
    height: 193px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 35px 0 0 40px;
    width: 186px;   
}
#body .body .section img {
    display: block;
}
#body .body .section a {
    color: #2a4f5e;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 145px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 145px;
}   
#body .body .section a:hover {
    color: #507685; 
}
#body .body .section img {
    border: 0;  
}
#body .body .article {
    background: url(images/bg-article.gif) no-repeat top center;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 19px 16px;
    width: 470px;   
}
#body .body .article img {
    border: 0;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}   
#body .body .article h4 {
    color: #2a4f5e;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 12px 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
#body .body .article h4 a {
    color: #2a4f5e;
    text-decoration: none;  
}
#body .body .article h4 a:hover {
    color: #507685; 
}
#body .body .article p {
    color: #2a4f5e;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
#body .body .article p a {
    color: #2a4f5e; 
}
#body .body .article p a:hover {
    color: #346b84; 
}
#body .footer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0 15px 0;
    width: 960px;   
}
#body .footer div {
    float: left;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#body .footer div ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
#body .footer div ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    padding: 0 0 15px;  
}
#body .footer h3 {
    color: #2a4f5e;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    margin: 0 0 12px 0;
    padding: 0; 
    text-align: justify;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#body .footer h3 a {
    color: #2a4f5e; 
    text-decoration: none;
}
#body .footer h3 a:hover {
    color: #507685; 
}
#body .footer .section {
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 220px;   
}
#body .footer ul li {
    background: url(images/border-dashed.gif) repeat-x bottom left; 
}
#body .footer ul li:last-child {
    background: none;   
}
#body .footer li p {
    color: #5d5d5d;
    font-size: 14px;    
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: justify;
}
#body .footer li p a {
    color: #5d5d5d; 
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#body .footer li p a:hover {
    color: #aeaeae; 
}
#body .footer li span {
    color: #aeaeae;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;    
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 5px 0 0;
    padding:0;
}
#body .footer ul.news li p {
    background: url(images/bullets.gif) no-repeat 0 8px;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}
#body .footer .featured {
    padding: 0 18px 0 24px;
    width: 438px;   
}
#body .footer .featured ul li {
    overflow: hidden;   
}
#body .footer .featured img {
    border: 1px solid #dbddde;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0; 
    padding: 1px;
}
#body .footer .featured p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
#body .contact,
#body .about,
#body .services,
#body .blog {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 25px 10px 50px 10px;   
    width: 940px;
}
#body h1 {
    color: #2a4f5e;
    font-size: 27px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 74px;
    line-height: 74px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    text-indent: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;  
}
#body .contact p {
    color: #7b7b7b;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 26px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 40px 0;    
    text-align: justify;
    width: 830px;
}
#body .contact p a {
    color: #7b7b7b; 
}
#body .contact p a:hover {
    color: #2a4f5e; 
}
#body .contact div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 30px 0;    
}
#body .contact div h3 {
    color: #5d5d5d;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0; 
}
#body .contact div ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;        
}
#body .contact div ul li {
    color: #5d5d5d;
    font-size: 14px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0; 
}
#body .about div {
    padding: 50px 0 0 0;    
}
#body .about h2 {
    color: #2a4f5e;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#body .about p {
    color: #5d5d5d;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    padding: 0; 
    text-align: justify;
    width: 830px;
}
#body .about p a {
    color: #5d5d5d;
}
#body .about p a:hover {
    color: #2a4f5e; 
}
#body .services div {
    overflow: hidden;   
    margin: 0;
    padding: 40px 0 0;
}
#body .services h2 {
    color: #2a4f5e;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#body .services h2 a {
    color: #2a4f5e; 
}
#body .services h2 a:hover {
    color: #507685; 
}
#body .services h3 {
    color: #2a4f5e;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 15px 0 0;
    padding: 0 30px 0 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;  
}
#body .services h3 a {
    color: #2a4f5e; 
}
#body .services h3 a:hover {
    color: #507685; 
}
#body .services h4 {
    color: #2a4f5e;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;  
}
#body .services p {
    color: #5d5d5d;
    font-size: 14px;    
    line-height: 24px;
}
#body .services p a {
    color: #5d5d5d; 
}
#body .services p a:hover {
    color: #2a4f5e; 
}
#body .services div ul {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 0 0;
    width: 312px;   
}
#body .services div ul li {
    background: url(images/bullets.gif) no-repeat center left;
    color: #5d5d5d;
    font-size: 14px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 12px;    
    text-align: left;
}
#body .services div div {
    overflow: hidden;   
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}
#body .services div div img {
    float: left;    
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}
#body .services div div p {
    padding: 0 30px 0 0;
    text-align: justify;    
}
#body .products {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 25px 0 70px 0;
    width: 960px;
}   
#body .products h2 {
    color: #2a4f5e; 
    font-size: 26px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 90px 0 30px 0; 
}
#body .products p {
    color: #5d5d5d;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;    
    text-align: justify;
}
#body .products p a {
    color: #5d5d5d; 
}
#body .products p a:hover {
    color: #2a4f5e; 
}
#body .products div {
    overflow: hidden;   
    margin: 0 0 45px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#body .products div div {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;   
}
#body .products div div h3 {
    color: #2a4f5e;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    text-align: justify;    
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#body .products div p {
    font-size: 16px;    
}
#body .products div div p {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: justify;    
}
#body .blog {
    overflow: hidden;   
}
#body .blog div {
    float: left;
    padding: 60px 0 0 0;
    width: 630px;   
}
#body .blog ul {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 38px 0 0 30px;
    width: 280px;   
}
#body .blog ul li {
    background: url(images/border-dashed.gif) repeat-x bottom left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 22px 0;    
}
#body .blog ul li:last-child {
    background: none;   
}
#body .blog h2 {
    color: #2a4f5e;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: capitalize; 
}
#body .blog h3 {
    color: #5d5d5d;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: justify;    
}
#body .blog h3 a {
    color: #5d5d5d; 
}
#body .blog h3 a:hover {
    color: #2a4f5e; 
}
#body .blog p {
    color: #5d5d5d; 
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: justify;
}
#body .blog p a {
    color: #5d5d5d; 
}
#body .blog p a:hover {
    color: #2a4f5e; 
}
#body .blog div p {
    padding: 15px 0;    
}
#body .blog div p.article {
    font-weight: bold;  
}
#footer {
    background: #f5f5f5 url(images/bg-footer.gif) repeat-x top left;    
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 960px;
    padding: 0;
}
#footer div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 26px 0 0;  
    width: 960px;
}
#footer div div {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 192px;   
}
#footer div div h3 {
    color: #818a8c;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#footer div div ul,
#footer div div ul li {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0; 
}   
#footer div div ul li {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #818a8c; 
}
#footer div a.facebook,
#footer div a.twitter {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 27px;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    text-indent: -99999em;
    width: 40px;    
}
#footer div a.facebook,
#footer div a.twitter {
    background: url(images/icons.gif) no-repeat;    
}
#footer div a.facebook {
    background-position: 0 0;
    margin: 10px 0 0 58px;
    _margin: 10px 0 0 28px;
}
#footer div a.twitter {
    background-position: 0 -37px;
}
#footer div p {
    color: #c1c1c1;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 30px 0;
    text-align: center; 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
```

My other CSS to overwrite.

```
/* 
    Document   : login
    Created on : Nov 15, 2012, 2:15:26 PM
    Author     : god-gavedmework
    Description:
        Purpose of the stylesheet follows.
*/



.overlap{
    background:none;
    height: 472px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 960px;   
}
table
{
    position:absolute;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;

}

.errorMessage {
color: red;
font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

Comment: Both answers are correct but i can only do a single check...

Comment: can you please explain why you down vote? i need to know why... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the visibility hidden that way it will take the same space but will be invisible

```
.overlap{
    background:none;
    height: 472px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 960px;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#body .header #prodoverlap{
    background:none;
    height: 472px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 960px;   
}
```

Please add this css code in your other CSS file
Thanks.